# How to avoid casting for wrapper objects in maps?

Tags: java, interface, casting

I have an interface FeatureValue which implements a function called pretty print.

I have two classes right now that implement that interface: FeatureString and FeatureList (The lists in FeatureList contain strings). These classes are just wrapper that store a string and a list respectively and implement the pretty print function for their wrapped values.

I have EnumMap which takes as keys some enums of type Feature (some which correspond to strings and some which correspond to lists).

I originally made this interface so that I could just iterate over the Enums and pretty print them. But now I want to be able to get the value from the wrapper FeatureValue as well.

Since I'm storing the enum map as `<Feature, FeatureValue>` , it doesn't know what type the wrapped value is so I have to cast when I get it.

Is there a way to refactor my code so that I don't need to cast, but still retain the ability to just iterate over the Enums and print them without knowing the type?

Enum

```
public enum Features
{
KIND("kind"),
RULE("rule"),
PROBLEM("problem"),

private String name;

Features(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
}
```

Interface

```
public interface FeatureValue
{
    public String prettyPrint();
}
```

List implementation (There's a similar one for FeatureString which I'll omit)

```
public class FeatureList implements FeatureValue
{
private final List<String> list;

public FeatureList(List<String> list)
{
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public String prettyPrint()
{
    return Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
}

public List<String> getList()
{
    return list;
}
}
```

Casting code

```
for(String token: ((FeatureList) enumMap.get(Feature.particularFeatureThatCorrespondsToLists)).getValue())
    doSomething(token);
```

There is a cast necessary since the map is parameterized for values of Feature, not FeatureList

Comment: Could we see some code?  It looks like you're missing a few things, like what you're "storing the enum map as."

Comment: yea i just noticed, I fixed that missing part

Comment: ok, I've added some code

Comment: you show us `FeatureValue` and `FeatureString`, but your problem is with `FeatureList`, `Feature` and `enumMap`. Show us the right code, please ;)

Comment: ok, I've added more code. I'm not sure what code you're referring to when you said enumMap, I already have it there under Casting Code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the method `getValue()` to your interface `FeatureValue` and make the interface parametrized.

*FeatureValue.java*

```
public interface FeatureValue<E> {

    String prettyPrint();    

    E getValue();

}
```

*FeatureList.java*

```
public class FeatureList implements FeatureValue<List<String>> {    

    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String prettyPrint() {
        return list.toString();
    }

    public List<String> getValue() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

*Main.java*

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    for (String each: getAsList(enumMap, Features.KIND)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

private static List<String> getAsList(
        EnumMap<Features, FeatureValue> enumMap, Features key) {
    FeatureValue value = enumMap.get(key);
    return value != null ? 
       ((FeatureList) value.getValue()).getValue() : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: I'm not instantiating FeatureLists, I'm getting them from inside the map which contains FeatureValues, which is why I need the cast in the first place.

Comment: True, the cast is still needed. The only thing I can think about is to create a method to do the casting, that will make the code cleaner. I'm afraid the casting is always necessary as your map stores an interface an the value returned depends on the real implementation of that interface. Edited my code

Answer (score 0):

Make your

```
public interface FeatureValue
{
    public String prettyPrint();
}
```

iterable, like this

```
public interface FeatureValue extends Iterable<String>
{
    public String prettyPrint();
}
```

this will make any `FeatureValue` to be iterable by foreach loops.

For classes that do not actually require iteration, either throw an exception

```
public class Stubbed1 extends FeatureValue {
    public Iterator<String> getIterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

or return an empty iterator

```
public class Stubbed2 extends FeatureValue {
    public Iterator<String> getIterator() {
        return Collections.<String>emptyList().iterator();
    }
}
```

For classes which requires iteration do the following

```
public class DocumentFeatureList implements FeatureValue
{
   private final List<String> list;

   ...

   public Iterator<String> getIterator() {
       return list.iterator();
   }
}
```